# How can i download AWS Trusted Advisor report from 100 accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want automate the download of AWS Trusted Advisor report from over 100 AWS accounts. I have tried API call but it returns data in JSON format, i need the data in CSV format. Have tried JSON to CSV converter but does not give the desired result.

Comment: You need to write a custom script to get the reports from all accounts. API calls will always return data in JSON. Your script would have to parse the data and convert it to CSV.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 do you have any python script to convert this kind of JSON data into CSV?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this right in the AWS console using AWS Trusted Advisor Org View and then you can generate specific reports and save them as a CSV file if you wish.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).